# PyCharmで二重引用符を使用して名前を指定すると、引用符内の文字が常にイタリック体になってしまう

Tags: python, pycharm

pythonを使用していて、""を使用して名前を指定しようと思ったら、""内の文字が常にイタリック体になってしまいます。
戻す方法を教えてください。

初心的な質問ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この辺で解説されているPyCharmエディタの元々の機能でしょうか。[色とフォントの構成 - 公式ヘルプ | PyCharm](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html) 好みに合うようにカスタマイズしていけば良いのでは？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実行はどのようなエディターを使用していますか？おそらくエディターの書式設定の問題が文字列がイタリック体になっている可能性もあるかもしれません！
fontの設定指示のコードをTkinter モジュールで、
create_text(" 文字",font =('フォント名',30))入れてみるとできるかどうか試してください！

Comment: 回答有難うございます